# How to apply a css style to all tables except one table?

Tags: html, css

So for example I have:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
}

.special {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>3</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>4</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td class="special">5</td></tr></table>
```

However for the 5th table I don't want to have the `<td>` right aligned, I want it to go back to the default `<td>` values.

In case you're wondering why it's because I'm combining a letterhead that uses a table (it can't use div's for reasons I won't go into right now), and as a result if the other portions include css styles for the table (so that you don't have to define each table, etc.), then the letterhead values take over the styles. **I know I could manually overwrite each one but I don't know which styles will be applied beforehand.**

Again yes I know it could be done with div tags but ignoring that how can I say don't apply any styles to the td tag in the 5th table? Or is there a way to reset all the defaults in the special definition?

***Update:** Keep in mind I'm combining files so the letterhead should be completely self-contained. The reason the `td:not` won't work is because I would need to specify this in all files that use the letterhead, which means every single file needs to know about the properties of the letterhead.

Comment: `.special {all: initial}` ? `.special {all: unset}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not()`

```
td:not(.special)
{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the issue is that to quote: "but I don't know which styles will be applied beforehand".

Comment: This doesn't work because I then need to specify td:not(.special) in all files that aren't the letterhead. Basically I need to keep the letterhead code completely self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option here is to use the [`:not` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```
td:not(.special)
{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wuy6yp59/4/

Another option is to override all properties with [`unset`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33834049/7586). This is assuming you do know the properties, but not the default values:

```
.special
{
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: unset;
}
```

But really, the easiest approach is usually to add a class to all of the non-special `td`s.

Comment: This doesn't work because I then need to specify td:not(.special) in all files that aren't the letterhead. Basically I need to keep the letterhead code completely self-contained.

Comment: I looked at unset but unfortunately it unsets everything in my renderer, including all additional properties I need to set to the table. That's the direction I was actually going towards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
td:not(.special) {
    text-align: right
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I then need to specify td:not(.special) in all files that aren't the letterhead. Basically I need to keep the letterhead code completely self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Using not selector, we can apply the style to all tables except one

```
<style>table:not(.diff)
  {
      color:#ff0000;
  }</style>
<table><tr><td>table1<td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>table2<td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>table3<td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>table4<td></tr></table>
<table class="diff"><tr><td>table5<td></tr></table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I then need to specify td:not(.special) in all files that aren't the letterhead. Basically I need to keep the letterhead code completely self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this.

The first one is use `:not ();` which is my advice.

The second one is you mention the classes of the table and use this: `.firstclass, . secondclass`.

Since you want to use the same styles for multiple pages, use this : `<link related="stylesheet" href="pagename">`. This is the external way of adding css.

Comment: Using not means that all files that are combined need to know about the letterhead css, which is terrible for maintenance. As for using firstclass, etc. this assumes I know all the styles that have been applied which I don't. In other words I don't know all the styles that have been in applied before I inject the letterhead html snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

**Most browsers will display the  element with the following default values:**

```
td {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}
td {
  text-align: right;
}
td.special {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>3</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>4</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td class="special">5</td></tr></table>
```

To know more about [**`td`**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp) tag.

Comment: Unfortunately no because you're assuming that only text-align is applied. I don't know all the css styles that have been applied in td.

Comment: You still have the same issue. For example what if I added bolding to the main td then your special would be bolded which is not what we want.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier , What you really want ?? . If you add something on your `td` it will effect all your other `td` then you want avoid only one `td` then you should write another `css` for that `td`.

Comment: But there should be a way to remove all inherited css styles for a specific element. The closest I came was "all:unset;" the only problem is that it doesn't work correctly everywhere.

Comment: Ok , i don't know more about this . 
`https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/` may be this could help.

Comment: That's basically all:unset; Unfortunately not all renderers support it.

Comment: Then , what you do ?? @StephaneGrenier

Answer (score -1):

I think the 'td.special' is going to take the alignment of the parent element. so usually it will be best if you set its own 'text-align' property to the value you want it to be.
say

```
.special { all: unset;}
```

Comment: text-align is just an example property, I don't know what the different properties will be...

Comment: Then i would suggest you go back to your question and edit it to reflect that you want all other properties to return to default. If you observe most of the answers here, almost all have the text-align property alone. So its kind of misleading

Comment: look at the new edit, it sets all the properties to their inheritable values and the rest to their default css specs. I hope this does it. Good luck