# Remove define css line in style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have Content file style1.css

```
 
<style>
a.color-1
{
    color: blue;
}

a.color-orther
{
   color: green;
}

a.color-3
{
  color: red; /* ---> right color */
}

 /** REMOVE define lines **/
div a 
{
   color: white !important;
}

<style>
```

HTML file embed css: style1.css

```
<div> 
  <a class="color-1  color-orther color-3  "  > tag </a> 
</div>
```

I want remove Rule: `div a .this-need-remove`
by redefine  ".this-need-remove" in HTML style

add style in HTML

```
div a 
{
   color: unset !important; /* --->  color-3 not working */
}
```

Comment: I assume you're not able to remove the class from the HTML...? If so, what restrictions do you have? It's trivial to remove the CSS rule, or just to make one or the other more specific.

Comment: your selectors are wrong you shouldn't have the space in between the a and the class.  Also can you clarify what you're trying to do - it's not very clear what that remove class is meant to do

Comment: "*by redefine ".this-need-remove" in HTML style*"  -> `$("a.color-3").removeClass("this-need-remove")`

Comment: As per comment above, but explicit: `a .color-3` -> `a.color-3`

Comment: `unset` doesn't mean "remove the previously set value" nor does it mean "not set"- it's a noun, not a verb - it has a specific meaning, see this question for more info and relevant links: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33834049/2181514

Comment: Sorry, i just edited my question, 
in tag <a> not has class